# github commits from IDEA don't showing in contribution activity

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

When I push changes to github (from intellij idea), they are only showing in repos pages, but not in a calendar and a contributions feed. 
The same problem in question [Contributing using git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870156/contributing-using-git), and the best answer is to write to support.

Maybe there are simpler ways to resolve this now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the **[contribution calendar](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-contributions#contributions-calendar)** only reflects contributions done on the **`master` branch** of repos.
Pushes for other branches wouldn't appear.
I do see a contribution [on your calendar](https://github.com/MikhailErofeev) for [your repo](https://github.com/MikhailErofeev/algothirms) (the second one might take a bit of time to appear: the refresh might not be immediate)

But... you still can [hack the contribution calendar ;)](http://bd808.com/blog/2013/04/17/hacking-github-contributions-graph/)

As the [OP Mikhail Erofeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1291049/mikhail-erofeev)'s [remarks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18684666/6309), and as described in [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile):

> **You'll need to link your git email to your GitHub account**, so that we'll know who to associate contributions with.
>   Once you do this, you might need to contact support so that we can backfill your previous contributions.

The other case is when you are pushing commits with the wrong email as author/committer: the [GitHub script (`git filter-branch`)](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info) would allow you to rectify the situation.

Answer (score 0):

here's answer: https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile
i was commiting from another email, and yes - i need contact support